# Можно ли разместить Java код на каком нибудь хостинге?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, хостинг

Есть готовый сервер написанный на Java сокетах, его цель обрабатывать запросы клиентов и возвращать им ответы, но проблема в том что компьютер (на котором работает приложение-сервер) имеет IP адрес из приватной сети, то есть "серый", соответственно клиентов с глобальной сети он обрабатывать не может. Для этих целей нужен публичный адрес. 
Возможности предоставить такой у провайдера нет. Вот думаю, можно ли поставить приложение-сервер на какой-то хостинг в интернете и использовать его IP адрес и порт? Посоветуйте пожалуйста, можно ли где-нибудь об этом почитать

Comment: redhat openshift, ms azure, heroku

Comment: Логично ли такое делать вообще?

Comment: ну если Вам надо, еще можно у провайдера купить сервер и адрес

Comment: heroku бесплатная

Comment: @michael_best условно, openshift тоже была, сейчас не знаю

Comment: Разместить можно, но надо знать правила.